# ¿Cómo se dice "with each passing minute/day/year..."?

Tags: traducción, expresiones, tiempo

Me gustaría conocer frases en español que signifiquen lo mismo que la siguiente frase en inglés:

> *"With each passing hour/day/year/etc ..."*

Por ejemplo:

> *"With each passing day, her knowledge of Spanish increased."*
>
> **_____?_____**, sus conocimientos de español aumentaban.

Cuando lo intento traducir directamente, mi opción es ***"Con cada día/año/etc pasado..."***

¿Es correcto? ¿Es esta una forma común de decir esto, o hay otras frases más comunes para este concepto?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In my answer I'm going to try to keep the translation as closer to the original phrase as possible, because there're so many valid ways to say the very same. So I'm going to be concret.

In the translation there's a little mistake. The verb. It's past, but It's in the wrong form.

> *With each passing hour/day/year/etc ...*

- Con cada día/hora/año **que pasaba**, sus conocimientos de español **crecían**.

The next one is another valid translation.

- Con cada día/hora/año **que pasaba** su *dominio* del español **mejoraba**.

A shorter way:

- Cada día/hora/año **que pasaba** su español **mejoraba**.

We can also change *cada (each)* by *el paso de*:

- Con **el paso de** los días/meses/años su español mejoraba.

Finally the shorter one:

- Con los días/horas/años su español **mejoraba**.

  *We have elided that the time goes by, we just mentioned days/months/years for such meaning*

Note that In spanish (at least in Spain), we speak about *improving* our language *skills* rather than *increasing* the *knowledge* about the language.

However, both ways (*to improve and to increase*) are interchangable in this phrase. Both are valid.

**Note**: *passing* is in continuous form. The -ing brings *motion* to the time. In spanish the motion has been introduced by **que**: *que pasaba*. This is the way we do reference explictly to the motion of the time.

If we want just to use the verb without *que*. We could also say:

- **Pasaban** los días/horas/años **y** su español **mejoraba**.

Semantically both say the very same. Sintactically both are differents. The last one would not be an acurated translation to the original one.

Comment: You can also say _**a** cada hora/mes/día/año/momento que pasaba_.

Comment: All your examples are good but I disagree when you say that the first one sounds forced. It only means something different but is ok. I'm a native spanish speaker and my spanish skills are quite good, however my main goal of participating on this forum is to increase my knowledge of the Spanish language. You can both improve your skills and grow your knowledge of a language. Anyway +1 good answer.

Comment: Well, that's why I said "sounds to me .. I would say". Just saying I'm not familiar with that way to speak about skills or knowledge. Anyways, as we see in the rest of the answers, there're many and good ways to say the very same. May be I should not mention my own preferences when answering questions here. It could lead to confusion.

Comment: Redited the answer. I removed references to personal opinions or preferences. They didn't bring valueable info to the answer.

Answer (score 3):

Apart from [Laiv's answer](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/18465/12637), there is a shorter way of saying the same:

> **[por momentos](http://dle.rae.es/?id=Pbn1zcv)**
>
> 1. loc. adv. progresivamente.
> 2. loc. adv. de un momento a otro.

So you can just say:

> Su español mejoraba por momentos.

The same is valid for other units of time:

> Su español mejoraba por días.

Another option:

> **[día a día](http://dle.rae.es/?id=DcsVyE1)**
>
> 2. loc. adv. De manera continuada y progresiva o reiterada.

So:

> Su español mejoraba día a día.

You can also say:

> Su español mejoraba día tras día.
>
> Su español mejoraba año tras año.

More options:

> [**de un día a otro**, o **de un día para otro**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=DcsVyE1)
>
> 1. locs. advs. En muy poco tiempo o de manera inminente.

So:

> Su español mejoraba de un día para otro.
>
> Su español mejoraba de un mes/año a otro.

Comment: Even shorter, just "Cada" ("Cada día, cada hora, cada minuto, su español mejoraba").

Answer (score 2):

As a venezuelan, I can tell by the way that we speak here, we say

> con cada día/hora/minuto que pasaba

Ejemplo:

> "Con cada día que pasaba, su conocimiento de Español mejoraba"

There are also another expressions as for example:

> Conforme corrían las horas

O

> Conforme pasaban las horas

Ejemplo:

> "Conforme corrían/psaban los días, su conocimiento de Español mejoraba"

Comment: That is correct but for the _present_ and the question refers to _past_ (increas**ed**) You can improve this answer given both examples of present and past since the other answers have not said anything about that.

Comment: DGaleano in that case, you could use "pasaba", thanks I'll correct this issue.